# Make a border span across higher-level containers

Tags: css, css-grid

I'd like to have a bottom border on my title that breaks the grid. There are 3 columns, left, middle, and right, and my title and content go in the middle. I'd like to have a bottom border extend all the way to the left side of the left column. Is there a better way to do this than what I came up with below? Does CSS grid provide a built-in mechanism for doing this sort of thing? I'd appreciate any suggestions.

```css
.grid-container {
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  [start] 1fr  [middle] 4fr  [end] 1fr ;
  
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.start {
  grid-column: start;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.middle {
  grid-column: middle;
}
.title {
  
 }
.title:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: calc(-25% - 1rem);
}
 
 .end {
   grid-column: end;
   background-color: #ccc;
 }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="start">Start</div>
    <div class="middle">
      <h2 class="title">My Title</h2>
      <div class="content">Some text lorem ipsum, whatever.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="end">End</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **negative margin** method seems to work. It's a bit clunky, but seems effective nonetheless.

You could also use **absolute positioning** to align that border under the title. The container would be the bounding box (i.e., `position: relative`). But that's also a bit clunky.

If you want a **pure grid solution**, that's also possible. The method I came up with is clean and effective. Some may consider it overkill for a simple border, but your need is somewhat unique, so this may be useful.

Here's the basic concept:

- Divide your container into 100 tiny rows (1px).
- Make your existing grid items span these rows from top to bottom.
- Now you're back to your original layout, but with an upgrade under the hood.
- You now have 100 places for a border line.
- Create a new grid item (either DOM or pseudo-element).
- Span the item across the row under your title.
- Voilà! :-)

```css
.grid-container {
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  [start] 1fr  [middle] 4fr  [end] 1fr ;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(100, 1px);        /* new */
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;                       /* adjusted; removed grid-row-gap */
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.start {
  grid-column: start;
  background-color: #ccc;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;                            /* new */
}

.middle {
  grid-column: middle;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;                            /* new */
}
 
 .end {
   grid-column: end;
   background-color: #ccc;
   grid-row: 1 / -1;                           /* new */   
 }
 
.grid-container::after {                       /* new */
   content: "";
   background-color: red;
   grid-row-start: 47;
   grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="start">Start</div>
    <div class="middle">
      <h2 class="title">My Title</h2>
      <div class="content">Some text lorem ipsum, whatever.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="end">End</div>
    <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/npddveag/3)

Comment: I like this suggestion but will have to think about whether I want to or can change the markup — it would be nice if I could avoid that, and it might be possible. Instead of adding <div class="border"> I added a new style for 
.grid-container:after with the same rules as border but the addition of content: ''; See my alternate answer below

Comment: Yes, you can use a pseudo element also. It becomes a grid item. Honestly, that's what I should have done. It's what I always do on my own sites. Not sure why it eluded me this time. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a modification of Michael_B's answer above. Seems to work the same but without the addition of markup to the original html.

```css
.grid-container {
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  [start] 1fr  [middle] 4fr  [end] 1fr ;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(100, 1px);        /* new */
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;                       /* adjusted; removed grid-row-gap */
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.start {
  grid-column: start;
  background-color: #ccc;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;                            /* new */
}

.middle {
  grid-column: middle;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;                            /* new */
}
 
 .end {
   grid-column: end;
   background-color: #ccc;
   grid-row: 1 / -1;                           /* new */   
 }
 
.grid-container:after {                                      /* new */
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  grid-row-start: 47;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="start">Start</div>
        <div class="middle">
            <h2 class="title">My Title</h2>
            <div class="content">Some text lorem ipsum, whatever.</div>
        </div>
    <div class="end">End</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, based on the same idea as Micheael_B had, "you need more rows".

What you can do is split the middle part in 3 parts. Title, border, content.
You can give each their own grid-row in order.

See fiddle that only works in Firefox because instead of unwrapping the 3 tags I used the display property `contents`
https://jsfiddle.net/npddveag/2/

The display property contents is a magic way of making the wrapper div disappear without the actual markup disappearing.(and inherited styles will stil apply, so there is a bit more to it). 
If you need it to work in other browsers you can just unwrap the 3 tags.